# How to extract multiple table tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from cvedetails.com for the product windows 10 and in the page source, there is a table. There is one tr for the details of the vulnerabilities and one tr for the description of the vulnerability
I want to be able to extract both tr as they are correlated

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php? vendor_id=26&product_id=32238&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov= 0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=845&sha=41e451b72c2e412c0a1cb8cb1dcfee3d16d51c44')

#print(r.text[0:500])
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

#results = soup.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'srrowns'})
#resultdesc = soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'cvesummarylong'})
#print(results[0:3])
#print(resultdesc[0:3])

results = soup.find_all(('tr',attrs={'class':'srrowns'}),('td',attrs= 
{'class':'cvesummarylong'}))
print(results[0:3])
```

The commented lines above is the one that succeeded but as separated values

```
</tr>
                    <tr class="srrowns">
                <td class="num">
                                        <a name="y2019"> </a>
                                        1                   </td>
                                    <td nowrap><a href="/cve/CVE-2019-0879/"  title="CVE-2019-0879 security vulnerability details">CVE-2019-0879</a></td>
                <td><a href="//www.cvedetails.com/cwe-details/119/cwe.html" title="CWE-119 - CWE definition">119</a></td>
                <td class="num">
                    <b style="color:red">
                                            </b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Exec Code Overflow                  </td>
                                    <td>2019-04-09</td>
                <td>2019-05-08</td>
                <td><div class="cvssbox" style="background-color:#ff9c20">7.2</div></td>
                <td align="center">None</td>
                <td align="center">Local</td>
                <td align="center">Low</td>
                <td align="center">Not required</td>
                <td align="center">Complete</td>
                <td align="center">Complete</td>
                <td align="center">Complete</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td class="cvesummarylong" colspan="20">
                    A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka &#039;Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability&#039;. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0846, CVE-2019-0847, CVE-2019-0851, CVE-2019-0877.                 </td>
            </tr>

                        <tr class="srrowns">
                <td class="num">
                                        <a name="y2019"> </a>
                                        2                   </td>
                                    <td nowrap><a href="/cve/CVE-2019-0877/"  title="CVE-2019-0877 security vulnerability details">CVE-2019-0877</a></td>
                <td><a href="//www.cvedetails.com/cwe-details/119/cwe.html" title="CWE-119 - CWE definition">119</a></td>
                <td class="num">
                    <b style="color:red">
                                            </b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Exec Code Overflow                  </td>
                                    <td>2019-04-09</td>
                <td>2019-05-08</td>
                <td><div class="cvssbox" style="background-color:#ff9c20">7.2</div></td>
                <td align="center">None</td>
                <td align="center">Local</td>
                <td align="center">Low</td>
                <td align="center">Not required</td>
                <td align="center">Complete</td>
                <td align="center">Complete</td>
                <td align="center">Complete</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td class="cvesummarylong" colspan="20">
                    A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka &#039;Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability&#039;. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0846, CVE-2019-0847, CVE-2019-0851, CVE-2019-0879.                 </td>
            </tr>
```

I want the results to be extracted in one line with the cve numbers, severity, etc. with the description
but the only method I tried that extracted both is separated

The end result is i need the details in the table and the description and be able to output them in a .csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which information exactly you are looking for, but there are a number of tables in that page and you can extract them - without regex. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('your url')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all('table')
my_table = pd.read_html(str(tables[4]))
```

To get the first row of that particular table:

```
print(my_table[0].iloc[0,:].dropna(axis=0,how='all'))
```

Output:

```
#                                         1
CVE ID                        CVE-2019-0879
CWE ID                                  119
Vulnerability Type(s)    Exec Code Overflow
Publish Date                     2019-04-09
Update Date                      2019-05-08
Score                                   7.2
Gained Access Level                    None
Access                                Local
Complexity                              Low
Authentication                 Not required
Conf.                              Complete
Integ.                             Complete
Avail.                             Complete
```

You can play with the index numbers of the tables, and see what else you can discover...

Answer (score 0):

Something like as follows? With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even) for handling row issue and append description to appropriate row.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?%20vendor_id=26&product_id=32238&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=%200&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=845&sha=41e451b72c2e412c0a1cb8cb1dcfee3d16d51c44')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
descs = [re.sub(r'\t+|(\n+)?',' ',item.text.strip()) for item in soup.select('#vulnslisttable tr:nth-child(odd)')[1:]]  #
items = [ item for item in soup.select('#vulnslisttable tr:nth-child(even)')]
results = []
i = 0

for desc in descs:
    row = [re.sub(r'\t+|(\n+)?',' ',item.text.strip()) for item in items[i].select('td')]
    row.append(desc)
    results.append(row)
    i+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
headers = [re.sub(r'\t+|(\n+)?',' ',item.text.strip()) for item in soup.select('#vulnslisttable th')]
headers.append('description')
df.columns = headers
print(df)
```

[regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/YGCDG5/1)

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Did you try these answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the full table, and then access your desired parameters:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, re
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?%20vendor_id=26&product_id=32238&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=%200&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=845&sha=41e451b72c2e412c0a1cb8cb1dcfee3d16d51c44').text, 'html.parser')
_t = d.find('table', {'id':'vulnslisttable'})
headers, [_, *data] = [re.sub('^[\t\n]+|[\t\n]+$', '', i.text) for i in _t.find_all('th')], [[re.sub('^[\s\t\n]+|[\t\n]+$', '', i.text) for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in _t.find_all('tr')]
result = [{**dict(zip(headers, data[i])), 'summary':data[i+1][0]} for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
```

Output (shortened, due to SO's character limit):

```
[{'#': '1', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0879', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0846, CVE-2019-0847, CVE-2019-0851, CVE-2019-0877."}, {'#': '2', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0877', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0846, CVE-2019-0847, CVE-2019-0851, CVE-2019-0879."}, {'#': '3', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0859', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in Windows when the Win32k component fails to properly handle objects in memory, aka 'Win32k Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0685, CVE-2019-0803."}, {'#': '4', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0856', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.0', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Single system', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when Windows improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '5', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0853', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-15', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that the Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) handles objects in the memory, aka 'GDI+ Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '6', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0851', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0846, CVE-2019-0847, CVE-2019-0877, CVE-2019-0879."}, {'#': '7', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0849', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '4.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows GDI component improperly discloses the contents of its memory, aka 'Windows GDI Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0802."}, {'#': '8', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0848', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the win32k component improperly provides kernel information, aka 'Win32k Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0814."}, {'#': '9', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0847', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0846, CVE-2019-0851, CVE-2019-0877, CVE-2019-0879."}, {'#': '10', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0846', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Windows Jet Database Engine improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Jet Database Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0847, CVE-2019-0851, CVE-2019-0877, CVE-2019-0879."}, {'#': '11', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0845', 'CWE ID': '20', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the IOleCvt interface renders ASP webpage content, aka 'Windows IOleCvt Interface Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '12', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0844', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows kernel improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows Kernel Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0840."}, {'#': '13', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0842', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that the VBScript engine handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows VBScript Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '14', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0841', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-15', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists when Windows AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC) improperly handles hard links, aka 'Windows Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0730, CVE-2019-0731, CVE-2019-0796, CVE-2019-0805, CVE-2019-0836."}, {'#': '15', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0840', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows kernel improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows Kernel Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0844."}, {'#': '16', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0839', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Terminal Services component improperly discloses the contents of its memory, aka 'Windows Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0838."}, {'#': '17', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0838', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when Windows Task Scheduler improperly discloses credentials to Windows Credential Manager, aka 'Windows Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0839."}, {'#': '18', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0837', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when DirectX improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'DirectX Information Disclosure Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '19', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0836', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '4.6', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'Partial', 'Avail.': 'Partial', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists when Windows improperly handles calls to the LUAFV driver (luafv.sys), aka 'Windows Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0730, CVE-2019-0731, CVE-2019-0796, CVE-2019-0805, CVE-2019-0841."}, {'#': '20', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0821', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '4.0', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Single system', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists in the way that the Windows SMB Server handles certain requests, aka 'Windows SMB Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0703, CVE-2019-0704."}, {'#': '21', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0814', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-11', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the win32k component improperly provides kernel information, aka 'Win32k Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0848."}, {'#': '22', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0805', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '4.6', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'Partial', 'Avail.': 'Partial', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists when Windows improperly handles calls to the LUAFV driver (luafv.sys), aka 'Windows Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0730, CVE-2019-0731, CVE-2019-0796, CVE-2019-0836, CVE-2019-0841."}, {'#': '23', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0803', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in Windows when the Win32k component fails to properly handle objects in memory, aka 'Win32k Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0685, CVE-2019-0859."}, {'#': '24', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0802', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '4.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows GDI component improperly discloses the contents of its memory, aka 'Windows GDI Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0849."}, {'#': '25', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0797', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in Windows when the Win32k component fails to properly handle objects in memory, aka 'Win32k Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0808."}, {'#': '26', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0796', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-05-08', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'None', 'Integ.': 'Partial', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists when Windows improperly handles calls to the LUAFV driver (luafv.sys), aka 'Windows Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0730, CVE-2019-0731, CVE-2019-0805, CVE-2019-0836, CVE-2019-0841."}, {'#': '27', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0795', 'CWE ID': '611', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-11', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Microsoft XML Core Services MSXML parser processes user input, aka 'MS XML Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0790, CVE-2019-0791, CVE-2019-0792, CVE-2019-0793."}, {'#': '28', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0794', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-11', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when OLE automation improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'OLE Automation Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '29', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0793', 'CWE ID': '611', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Microsoft XML Core Services MSXML parser processes user input, aka 'MS XML Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0790, CVE-2019-0791, CVE-2019-0792, CVE-2019-0795."}, {'#': '30', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0792', 'CWE ID': '611', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Microsoft XML Core Services MSXML parser processes user input, aka 'MS XML Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0790, CVE-2019-0791, CVE-2019-0793, CVE-2019-0795."}, {'#': '31', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0791', 'CWE ID': '611', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Microsoft XML Core Services MSXML parser processes user input, aka 'MS XML Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0790, CVE-2019-0792, CVE-2019-0793, CVE-2019-0795."}, {'#': '32', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0790', 'CWE ID': '611', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists when the Microsoft XML Core Services MSXML parser processes user input, aka 'MS XML Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0791, CVE-2019-0792, CVE-2019-0793, CVE-2019-0795."}, {'#': '33', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0786', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-09', 'Update Date': '2019-04-11', 'Score': '7.5', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'Partial', 'Avail.': 'Partial', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in the Microsoft Server Message Block (SMB) Server when an attacker with valid credentials attempts to open a specially crafted file over the SMB protocol on the same machine, aka 'SMB Server Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '34', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0784', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '7.6', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'High', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that the ActiveX Data objects (ADO) handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows ActiveX Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '35', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0782', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows kernel fails to properly initialize a memory address, aka 'Windows Kernel Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0702, CVE-2019-0755, CVE-2019-0767, CVE-2019-0775."}, {'#': '36', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0776', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the win32k component improperly provides kernel information, aka 'Win32k Information Disclosure Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '37', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0775', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '1.9', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows kernel improperly handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows Kernel Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0702, CVE-2019-0755, CVE-2019-0767, CVE-2019-0782."}, {'#': '38', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0774', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '4.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows GDI component improperly discloses the contents of its memory, aka 'Windows GDI Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0614."}, {'#': '39', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0772', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that the VBScript engine handles objects in memory, aka 'Windows VBScript Engine Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0665, CVE-2019-0666, CVE-2019-0667."}, {'#': '40', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0767', 'CWE ID': '200', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '+Info ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '2.1', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Partial', 'Integ.': 'None', 'Avail.': 'None', 'summary': "An information disclosure vulnerability exists when the Windows kernel improperly initializes objects in memory.To exploit this vulnerability, an authenticated attacker could run a specially crafted application, aka 'Windows Kernel Information Disclosure Vulnerability'. This CVE ID is unique from CVE-2019-0702, CVE-2019-0755, CVE-2019-0775, CVE-2019-0782."}, {'#': '41', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0766', 'CWE ID': '264', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': '', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-09', 'Score': '7.2', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Local', 'Complexity': 'Low', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in Windows AppX Deployment Server that allows file creation in arbitrary locations. To exploit the vulnerability, an attacker would first have to log on to the system, aka 'Microsoft Windows Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability'."}, {'#': '42', 'CVE ID': 'CVE-2019-0765', 'CWE ID': '119', '# of Exploits': '', 'Vulnerability Type(s)': 'Exec Code Overflow ', 'Publish Date': '2019-04-08', 'Update Date': '2019-04-10', 'Score': '9.3', 'Gained Access Level': 'None', 'Access': 'Remote', 'Complexity': 'Medium', 'Authentication': 'Not required', 'Conf.': 'Complete', 'Integ.': 'Complete', 'Avail.': 'Complete', 'summary': "A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that comctl32.dll handles objects in memory, aka 'Comctl32 Remote Code Execution Vulnerability'."}, ...]
```